# SwiftUI: How to disable scrolling in List without disabling content

Tags: list, swiftui

I have a list in SwiftUI declared as follows:

```
List {
  Text("Test")
  Text("Test)
  ...
  Toggle(...)
}
```

I'd like to make this list ***unscrollable*** without using `.disabled(true)`, as I'd like the toggle to be interactable. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: try using a `VStack` instead of a `List`.

Comment: Could use a ForEach... Not scrollable by default!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```swift
List {
  Text("Test")
  Text("Test)
  ...
  Toggle(...)
}
.scrollDisabled(true)
```

See: https://sarunw.com/posts/disable-scrolling-swiftui/

Answer (score 1):

Put this below the list:

```
                .onAppear {
                    
                    UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false

                }
```

Comment: This didn't do anything for me